# new to c problem with simple game problem with function

Tags: c

im new to c i try to make a little and very simple game of hangedman and i dont know why doesent work get error in gcc "expected declaration or statement at the end of input"
im new to c and ii try very hard to learn it.
im missing something? my function is not right? some advice to learn alghorytmically thinking?
thanx in advance for the hel you gonna give me

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//function to find letter in string
int findletter(char y)
{
    char c;
    int i;
    char secret[] = "outcast";


    i = 0;

    scanf("%c", &c);
    while (c != secret[i] && i < strlen(secret))
        i++;
    if(c == secret[i])
        return (1);
    else
        return (0);
}
//confirmation letter
int guessed(char a)
{
    int z;
    char guess [6] = {0};

    z = 0;
    while(findletter(guess[z]) != 1 && findletter(guess[z]) < 6)
    {
        z++;
        if(findletter(guess[z]) == 1)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    


//word guessed
int tryguess(char v)
{
    int x;

    x = 0;
    while(findletter(guess[x]) == 0)
    {
        x++;
        if(findletter(guess[x] == 1))
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
}

int main()
{
    char secret[] = "outcast";
    char letter;
    int lives;
    char guess [6] = {0};
    int i;

    lives = 10;
    i = 0;

    printf("welcome to the hanged man\n");
    while(i < 6)
    {
        if((findletter(secret[i] == 1)))
            printf("%c", secret[i]);
        else
            printf("*\n");
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]" to learn how this site works. -- Count your curly braces. It helps if you adopt an indentation style and stick to it. Many problems are cured with this.

Comment: Line numbers in code snippets are **extremely annoying** as it renders your code useless for reproducing the problem. We'll have to snip those out. It also confuses the syntax highlighter.

Comment: Tip: It's normally `return 1` not `return (1)`. `return` is not a function. It's a keyword. You can also do `return c == secret[i]` and skip all the other mess.

Comment: Tip: If you're using `int` as a boolean then it's better to say `if (x)` or `if (!x)` than to say `if (x == 1)` or `if (x == 0)`.

Comment: Please post *the exact error text*, not just a snippet of it.

Comment: Hint: Is the `guessed()` function properly closed? Doesn't look like it.

Answer (score 0):

Correction to your code...

```
 int guessed(char a)
 {
         int z;
         char guess [6] = {0};
 
         z = 0;
         while(findletter(guess[z]) != 1 && findletter(guess[z]) <     6)
         {
                 z++;
                 if(findletter(guess[z]) == 1)
                         return 1;
                 else
                         return 0;
          }  // you forgot closing while loop here
 }    // function closing parenthesis
 //word guessed
```

**Advice**:

I don't know how much you had practice and how much you had learned yet..but on observing your mistake above I would like to suggest that whenever you create **function** or **loop** always write its prototype first, let's say you want to create a function for adding two numbers..

**STEP 1**: write prototype

```
int add(int x, int y)
{
//then do your stuff here...
return 0;
}
```

This will eliminate you chances of making error of parentheses...

Answer (score 0):

There are **a lot** of issues with this program, from both a syntax standpoint and a logical one.

General issues include:

- Function `guessed` and its `while` loop are not closed (missing `}`).
- There is a lot of unused code (functions and variables).
- The line `if((findletter(secret[i] == 1)))` compares the character value of `secret[i]` with `1` and passes that result to `findletter`. This doesn't matter though since you don't use this argument, and take user input within the function.
- You have hardcoded strings and lengths, which makes your program less dynamic and harder to change in the future.
- Using `while` loops as guards (in the unused functions `tryguess` and `guessed`), that are always exited on the first iteration.
- `findletter` simply checks if `secret` contains the character `c`, returning on the first occurrence.

It could be more clearly expressed as:

```
int findletter(char unused) {
    char secret[] = "secret",
         c;

    scanf(" %c", &c);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(secret); i++)
        if (secret[i] == c)
            return 1;

    return 0;
}
```

With that said, `findletter` would be better if you passed both the `secret` and `c` as arguments, so that you can use it more generically, and decouple user input from the function itself.

*(Or you could simply use the standard library function [`strchr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr) which achieves a very similar goal.)*

- The pattern of

```
if (a == b)
    return 1;
else 
    return 0;
```

can simply be reduced to

```
return a == b;
```

---

Aside from the issues above, the structure of your program doesn't make much sense. If our program worked, you'd basically be asking the player to guess a word of unknown length, one character of the word at a time. They can also simply guess any letter to display the current one. One could 'solve' the entire word `"secret`" by simply inputting `'s'` repeatedly.

The structure of a very basic hangman program is:

1. Select the *word* to be guessed. Select number of lives.
2. Create a blanked version of *word* to track progress. Display this blanked version, which indicates the length to the player.
3. Ask the player to guess a *letter*. Skip those already guessed.
4. Update all positions in the blanked version where *letter* appears in the *word*.

   - Decrement lives on miss, end game if out of lives.
5. Check if the amount of characters changed in the blank version matches the length of *word*.

   - Win condition, or return to step 3.

There are many different ways to achieve this, and there are likely thousands of examples online.

Here is a rough program that is about as simple as it gets. This showcases the usual structure and flow of a game of hangman.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

size_t update_all(char *to, const char *from, size_t len, char g) {
    size_t changed = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
        if (from[i] == g) {
            to[i] = g;
            changed++;
        }

    return changed;
}

void play_hangman(const char *word, unsigned lives) {
    size_t word_length = strlen(word),
           blanked_length = 0;

    char blanked[word_length + 1],
         guess = '\0';

    for (size_t i = 0; i < word_length; i++)
        blanked[i] = '*';
    blanked[word_length] = '\0';

    while (lives) {
        printf("The word: [%s]\n"
                "(Lives = %u) Enter a guess: ",
                blanked,
                lives);

        scanf(" %c", &guess);

        if (strchr(blanked, guess)) {
            printf("[%c]: Already guessed!\n", guess);
            continue;
        }

        size_t found = update_all(blanked, word, word_length, guess);
        blanked_length += found;

        if (!found) {
            printf("[%c]: NOT FOUND!\n", guess);
            lives--;
        } else
            printf("[%c]: FOUND!\n", guess);

        if (!lives)
            puts("Out of lives! You lose!");
        else if (blanked_length == word_length) {
            printf("You win! Word is [%s].\n", word);
            return;
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    play_hangman("secret", 10);
}
```

Note that this program is far from perfect, as it doesn't fully keep track of guessed letters, so the player can guess the same wrong letter multiple times, and lose a life every time. To fix this, we would need even more *state*, collecting each guess the player makes, and use that data instead of the naive `if (strchr(blanked, guess))`.

It also makes use of the `'*'` character as a sentinel value, which would cause confusion if our word contained `'*'`. To fix this, we could use an array of boolean values indicating the correctly guessed letters in the word thus far, and use this to print our word character-by-character. Or we could restrict character inputs with functions like [`isalpha`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isalpha).

This program simply serves as an example that for a proper approximation of the typical "Hangman" you need to handle more *game state* than you have.

*(Error handling omitted for brevity throughout this answer.)*